# Importing file to Access via VBA with wildcard on name

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Is there anyway i can use an wildcard when importing a file (excel spreadsheet for example) via VBA in Access?

I have the following code:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9,    "Table", "C:\Files\Process A\1.Input\*.XLSX", True
```

There is always just one file in the above folder, but with different names everyday, so i need some sort of wildcard.

Is there anyway to do it?

Thank you,
Vítor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"There is always just one file" -> So get the filename with `Dir()` and put a variable in your arguments

see https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Worked really well. Thank you.